# Evaluate the limit $\log\log f(x)/\log x$

Tags: analysis

> Let a function $f\colon [1,\infty) \to (1,\infty)$ be monotone increasing and $f$ satisfies $f(x)^2 \le f(4x) \le 2013^{\sqrt x}$. Evaluate
>   $$
> \lim_{x \to\infty} \frac{\log\log f(x)}{\log x}.
> $$

The clipped picture might be a hint..

[image]

Comment: can you translate this?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I did.

Comment: The hint is wrong: we have $f(x/4)\le f(x)$, but only if $x/4\ge1$; unfortunately, the sequence $x/2^n\to0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numerator $log(log f(x))$ when $x \rightarrow +\infty $ goes to $+\infty$. We have the same behavior for the denominator. So by applying the de l'Hôpital theorem we have

\begin{equation}
lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{loglogf(x)}{logx} = lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\frac{d}{dx} \left(loglogf(x)\right)}{\frac{d}{dx} log(x)}
\end{equation}

Now you know that $f(x) \leq \sqrt{2013^\sqrt{x}}$. Then you can replace f(x) by $\sqrt{2013^\sqrt{x}}$. When doing so, you have

\begin{equation}
lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{loglogf(x)}{logx} = lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt(x) log(2013)}{4 log(\sqrt(2013^{\sqrt(x)}))}= \frac{1}{2}
\end{equation}